# ReactNativeBlobUtil Error: Download interrupted

Tags: javascript, react-native

## Problem Description

RN Project Version: 0.72.1

---

ReactNativeBlobUtil (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util) Version: ^0.18.3

---

I've created a function for my React Native application that downloads a webm audio file given a URL (passed URL returns audio/webm) and filename (passed filename always ends in .webm). While it sometimes completely downloads the audio file correctly to the downloads folder, other times it stops halfway and throws **Error: Download interrupted**. I've checked the URLs that lead to these errors and they're still visible in the browser so I don't understand why this error is happening. Examples of URLs which lead to these errors include:

- https://rr5---sn-hp57ynss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1688961952&ei=QC-rZKXBIoHuuwLJqorQBA&ip=2603%3A9001%3A6302%3A32c1%3A59e3%3A20c2%3A8e05%3Abb26&id=o-AP6Rq2SxqG9eAGGQzL7HqREpKfK2D77bN6mL52bn_bC0&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=cs&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-hp57ynss%2Csn-q4flrnsl&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=36&initcwndbps=2041250&spc=Ul2Sq9etje0MBIUGO_TqC9Q8_JFK0TDnGC5lqGRTmg&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=eCIricjNhpgxbnDQis8AXWgO&gir=yes&clen=2709916&dur=171.021&lmt=1669735064215628&mt=1688939831&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&beids=24350017&c=WEB&txp=5532434&n=EnAWhuYECKVW1-4F&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgP2yV5pW02p5BgXFSC00n2Tg75Tc9QY2D4RuMMCq66NICIADi80jdr9Nxycg27R5OQfH7_5lp2vc8p2OVHWCmHsXk&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAI3nwg0ZCgNnVUfTZPsmnRgHngaNrgjSWWbsWfaFjEVrAiEA_bUex3-7nyOuZt0oPdVHDP2YNMubzIOb5pGfQDPzQyM%3D
- https://rr3---sn-hp57yn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1688961961&ei=SS-rZK6OM__JzN0P5aqO0Aw&ip=2603%3A9001%3A6302%3A32c1%3A59e3%3A20c2%3A8e05%3Abb26&id=o-AHoEHhghcnvH7FDeddQRsQUydPHlFPf12KwAdZZiA-aV&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=L_&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-hp57yn7y%2Csn-hp57knds&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=36&initcwndbps=2203750&spc=Ul2Sq1Eva7elMiq1DDrUgijXS8ouRejddg4pIymtng&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=Pnqu4UYAeT-_qiwqp7qQlQoO&gir=yes&clen=1617125&dur=265.021&lmt=1685782147134072&mt=1688940064&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&beids=24350017&c=WEB&txp=4532434&n=quLGd3r4-Y34QtCO&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhAPN-3ssbJstWWkYFwABmbCIL3EXAvnPS6WZmzp55eZOaAiBRtwHabfYmGuIaiX-TTdPh-ulaUTjDqumgrXbRA2OP_w%3D%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgbV3EdIPmLzDvp6DrHKjKVLeqR1Vcu4IvpSRqKmHLYtkCICyylPu4f0gDL2idsnIPnB7LvHp8H-lijHOrfsHRymSi
- https://rr5---sn-hp57ynss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1688961966&ei=TS-rZLL9OeipzN0P3oihqAY&ip=2603%3A9001%3A6302%3A32c1%3A59e3%3A20c2%3A8e05%3Abb26&id=o-AGrjqxFSHzVKLeJ6G6I_63ZU247FShQM35TwYk4b0eB8&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=uN&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-hp57ynss%2Csn-q4fl6nsr&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=36&initcwndbps=2203750&spc=Ul2SqyOpnslAjeopzkNQUxoIjB_NBmrOeQl23aO96g&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=2MRir9F5TZO6_qSffBt_cl0O&gir=yes&clen=1627648&dur=270.021&lmt=1665296376411965&mt=1688940064&fvip=4&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&beids=24350017&c=WEB&txp=5432434&n=SlhSQMV0QBA75Qoh&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhALG1OQnojM2i0bUoQ7RgUqNARWAULo9NZrWBTyxPXvD2AiEAhe663FBS3QAdiy7R4iXWQydMfGIgpiq_skwVftXGHjI%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAIOFwlAeJIDrYUzLdLK_FkX_7PP_AucUR4K-N4TGcb1rAiEA_9gOgVEegxnHQ1uEaww4aMUtC583m0xwjjRSdxKoAFs%3D

I don't know if these links are still going to be live when this question is seen as they have an expiration date. By the way, these links are generated by the react-native-ytdl library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ytdl) version ^4.8.3 and I'm using an Android to test the app.

## Function Definition:

```
const downloadFile = async (url: string, fileName: string) => {
        try {
            const storagePermissionGranted = await requestStoragePermission();
            if (storagePermissionGranted) {
                const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
                const fileDir = Platform.OS === "android" ? dirs.DownloadDir : dirs.DocumentDir;
                const filePath = `${fileDir}/${fileName}`;
                
                const options = {
                    path: filePath
                };

                const task = ReactNativeBlobUtil.config( options ).fetch("GET", url, { "Cache-Control": "no-store", "Accept": "audio/webm" }); 
                task.then(result => {
                    console.log("Main file downloaded to: ", result.path());
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(`Error while downloading main file ${fileName} with primary address ${url} and path ${filePath}:`, error);
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error while requesting storage permission:", error);
        }
};
```

I've also tried a function definition like below but it still leads to the same error.

```
const downloadFile = async (url: string, fileName: string, backupUrl: string) => {
        try {
            const storagePermissionGranted = await requestStoragePermission();
            if (storagePermissionGranted) {
                const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
                const fileDir = Platform.OS === "android" ? dirs.DownloadDir : dirs.DocumentDir;
                ReactNativeBlobUtil
                    .config({
                        fileCache: true,
                        appendExt: "webm",
                    })
                    .fetch("GET", url, { "Cache-Control": "no-store" })
                    .then(async (cacheResult) => {
                        console.log(cacheResult);
                        let copyResult = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.MediaCollection.copyToMediaStore({
                        name: fileName,
                        parentFolder: "",
                        mimeType: "audio/webm"
                        }, "Audio", cacheResult.path());
                        console.log(copyResult);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(`Error while downloading main file ${fileName} with primary address ${url} and path ${filePath}:`, error);
                //     })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error while requesting storage permission:", error);
        }
};
```